# How can I increase the size of background of h1? CSS

Tags: css, image

This is the problem I have. I couldn't solve it. I think it's because I've just started learning something and then I tried the make my own little project to practice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kPkQ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your h1 you are setting the padding to be 0 10px, whereas the second value determines the padding for each side of the x-axis. Would you reach your goal if you just set the padding of the h1 to be `padding: 10px`?

You could possibly add the h1-tag within a parent-container and specify the width and height of that and then center-align the h1.

Comment: Appreciate friend! It's done but here is a question for you? How can I remember those things like I have something In my mind but I don't remember which code to use? What would you suggest?

Comment: It will come naturally with time when you have written more code. Just be patient, we have all been there. Repetition is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Add some padding in `Line 9`

`padding: {here} 10px;`